# Python Analysis: Type Checking Mode in VS CODE

Tags: visual-studio-code, python-typing, python-3.10, pyright

I changed the settings "Python Analysis: Type Checking Mode" to strict mode

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ni6ry.png)

And I get an error while checking for an instance of str,

```py
def is_name(name: str) -> bool:
    if isinstance(name, str):
        return True
```

`Unnecessary isinstance call; "str" is always an instance of`

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BcoHE.png)

Is this a code problem or a settings problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happens because you already annotated the `name` parameter as `str`, so it seems silly to narrow the type again after that with `isinstance`.

I personally find the error message a bit misleading because from a runtime perspective `name` could of course be something else (up until the `isinstance` check), i.e. it is technically not *"always an instance of `str`"*. But from a static type checker's perspective that complaint makes sense.

Python is a dynamically typed language and that philosophy carries over to type annotations. There is a reason they are also referred to as "type **hints**". It is extremely un-pythonic to strictly check the argument types inside a function.

That is what the annotations are for. They tell the user of the function: *"These are the types I expect in the body of this function. You **can** pass something else, but it might cause errors, unexpected behavior or break everything. Do it at your own peril."*

I assume there is more going on in your *actual* function because right now it seems semantically redundant. But my suggestion is to get rid of the `isinstance` check. Did you decide to annotate the `name` parameter with the type `str`? Good. Then proceed in the function body under the assumption that that is what the argument will be. It is not your job, to check the type. It is the **caller's** job to call your function properly (or handle the consequences).

Comment: Ok thanks, that's an interesting way of working to assume that the information you're getting is correct information, I think one of the SOLID principles speaks to that...
This error message is indeed misleading

Answer (score 0):

It is a code problem. Technically, your function can accept non-string values for the argument `name`. I would fix it like this:

```py
from typing import Any
def is_name(name: Any) -> bool:
    if isinstance(name, str):
        return True
```

Now this might seem wrong if you are using type-hints as a sort of documentation. A way to inform user what type to provide. But if your code *does handle* type Any, then they are allowed types.